# How to match JSON in wiremock which has values same for fields but may not be in same order

Tags: web-services, request, matching, wiremock

I have request JSON body
    
    `[ 
      {"name" : "Ram"},
      {"name" : "Sam"}
    ]`

and this is the input for wiremock request
I need to match the request even if the JSON has same content but values may not be in same order. Example,
    
    `[ 
      {"name" : "Sam"},
      {"name" : "Ram"}
    ]`

The method which I use is `.withRequestBody. I tried with`equalToJson` but does not work. What is that matcher which checks only JSON contents and not order ?

Answer (score 5):

This can be resolved using JsonPath that is part of the [bodyPatterns](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#equality-matching) equality matching functionality.

```
{
  "request" : {
    "urlPathPattern" : "/jpath/.*",
    "method" : "GET",
     "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.name == 'Sam')]"
    } ]   
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "Works"
  }
}
```

Using a [JsonPath online evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/) it is easy to test JsonPath expressions. For more details on what is possible have a look [here](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html).